# Как подключить правильную библиотеку для платежей в python telebot

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть телеграмм бот , что то типо интернет-магазина , и нужно подключить оплату , да такую что бы при успешной оплате бот присылал пользователю что то вроде квитанции или сообщение что ваш платеж прошел успешно , а при ошибке выдавал что оплата не прошла , пробовал free kassa но там все на php (мне нужен питон) , яндекс пей тоже почему то не работает , нужна корректная ссылка на форму с оплатой и что бы бот мог распознать эту оплату

Answer (score 0):

Отправку сообщения об успешной оплате или об ошибках программируете Вы, а не библиотека. Библиотека даёт информацию, Вы с этой информацией работаете, грубо говоря.

Правильной библиотеки не существует, берите ту, которая Вам нравится, и работайте с платёжным агрегатором, который Вы считаете максимально удобным.

P.S. Как это так, Вы не нашли ничего на Python?
https://github.com/Churakovmike/free-kassa-py